# Can't forward ssh port properly on fritzbox 6490

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I tried to forward port 8022 to port 22 on my raspberry pi in my fritzbox 6490.
Therefore I added the port forwarding rule for udp as well as for tcp.

My problem is, I keep getting a timeout error which tells "Bad File Number"

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong here, or how to conquer that problem?
I'm googling for 2 hours now but could not find a solution to my issue.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Port Forward settings?

Comment: troubleshoot, use nc and nmap and see if the port is open. See if it's a port forwarding issue or an ssh issue. see if any other port forwarding works